# App Under Construction

Tags: facebook

I have been building a Facebook app.  I have a development version and a test version running.  When I migrated the code to the production site and created the production version I get "The Hat Shop is under construction. Please try again later."  with instructions to enter a Connect URL in the applications settings.  I do not see any place to do this.

I am assuming I am missing something simple and obvious.  What is it?

I, of course, found the solution as soon as I posted the question.

Under the Advanced settings it was set to a web application as opposed to a Facebook application.  Changing that setting made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the application's settings in the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and ensure that the URLs listed in the basic settings are correct for the production website.